Populating ListBox. "Run-time error '380': Could not set the List property. Invalid property value."
I always get error on column 11 when trying to populate ListBox.
I have excel table in sheet Evaluations with test data from B3 to P24. The first 4 columns are text data, remaining 11 columns are numbers between 1 and 100
The first row of the table contains in column 4 text - assessors name that is selected in combobox.
I have created Userform on which I have placed ListBox. I also have a combobox with Assessors names. I want to populate the ListBox only with the records where in column 4 is name of the Assessor selected in combobox.
Upon initializing UserForm I call sub FilterPopulateListBox.
    Private Sub FilterPopulateListBox()
        Dim PSelectedAssessor As String
        PSelectedAssessor = CmbAssessors.Value  ' Get the currently selected assessor's name
    
        Dim PWs As Worksheet
        Set PWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluations")
        Dim PLastRow As Long
        PLastRow = PWs.Cells(PWs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
        Dim PData As Range
        Set PData = PWs.Range("B3:P" & PLastRow)
    
        ' Clear previous entries in the ListBox
        With lstEvaluations
            .Clear
            .ColumnCount = 15  ' Assuming there are 15 columns from B to P
            .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50"
    
        
     Debug.Print lstEvaluations.ColumnCount  ' Should print 15
            
            ' Loop through each row in the range and add to ListBox if the fourth column matches
            Dim PRow As Range
            For Each PRow In PData.Rows
                If PRow.Cells(1, 4).Value = PSelectedAssessor Then  ' Check if fourth column matches the ComboBox
                    Dim PRowArray() As Variant
                    PRowArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(PRow.Value))
                    .AddItem PRowArray(1)  ' Add first column value
                    Dim i As Integer
                    For i = 1 To UBound(PRowArray)  ' Add other columns
                        .List(.ListCount - 1, i - 1) = CStr(PRowArray(i))
                    Next i
                End If
            Next PRow
        End With
    End Sub

on this line of the code
.List(.ListCount - 1, i - 1) = CStr(PRowArray(i))

I always get error when i=11
When i=11 the value of PRowArray(i) is 17 and the line
.List(.ListCount - 1, i - 1) = PRowArray(i)

shows error window

Run-time error '380':
Could not set the List property. Invalid property value.

When debugging when I point with cursor at the beginning of the line at .List(.ListCount - 1, i - 1) it says. "Could not get the List property. Invalid argument" but PRowArray(i) is showing value 17.
When i is less then 11 it shows eiter 'Null' (before executing that line - when the line is highlighted) or value of the PRowArray(i) when the line is extecuted and next line is highlighted.

I have ensured that listbox has 15 columns.
I have nested PRowArray(i) into CStr(PRowArray(i)) to solve if there were some I don't know what issues with data.
I have debugged the code to see what kind of values the code reads for i 1 to 11. It all reads correctly even when i=11 and I point to PRowArray(i) the value is correctly 17

I read forums and
I asked ChatGpt3.5

Loading the list box in this way allows maximum 10 columns (from 0 to 9).

In order to accomplish what you try you need to use .list = myArray. Which is able to load much more columns. But having already values added you should use myArray = .column, then preserve existing and add the new data.

A Userform has not only a built-in limitation of 10 columns when using the .AddItem method.
It even ignores it when the .ColumnWidth property is explicitly set to more columns - it'll assume a starting value of 10 columns only resulting in Error 380 ( List prop couldn't be set - Invalid property value).
Generally you can overcome this limitation by two ways:



Firstly by assigning a 2D-array to the .List (or .Column) property - this is called array method, c.f. my earlier post Populate Listbox with multiple columns for further in-depth details.




If you stick to .AddItem you can benefit from a very minimal array assignment to the .List property based on the actual columns count via the following procedure as initial code step after defining the wanted columns count:



Sub fixColumnCount(lbx As MSForms.ListBox, ByVal colCnt As Long)
'Auth.: T.M. (c) 2023-08
'Purp.: fix ColumnCount to an exact number (even greater than default of 10 cols) !!!!!!!!!!!!!
'Note:  example call (here: to number of column captions (Row 1:1) in given range)
'       fixColumnCount Me.ListBox1, rng.Columns.Count + 1

    With lbx
        .ColumnCount = colCnt
         '.Column = Split(String(.ColumnCount, " "), " ")
        .Column = Split(Space(.ColumnCount))       ' assign initial Array of empty strings to .Column prop
        .Clear
    End With
End Sub



There is a limit for using unbound data source in ListBox. The max cols are 10 (index 0~9). The error is arised at i=11 (col index 10).

Consider populating the listbox with an array, especially when dealing with more than 10 columns.


Option Explicit
Private Sub FilterPopulateListBox()
    Dim PSelectedAssessor As String
    PSelectedAssessor = CmbAssessors.Value  ' Get the currently selected assessor's name
    Dim PWs As Worksheet
    Set PWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' modify as needed
    Dim PLastRow As Long
    PLastRow = PWs.Cells(PWs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim PData As Range
    Set PData = PWs.Range("B3:P" & PLastRow)
    Dim arrRes(), iR As Long, i As Integer
    ReDim arrRes(1 To 15, 1 To PData.Rows.Count)
    ' Clear previous entries in the ListBox
    With lstEvaluations
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 15  ' Assuming there are 15 columns from B to P
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50"
        Debug.Print lstEvaluations.ColumnCount  ' Should print 15
        ' Loop through each row in the range and add to ListBox if the fourth column matches
        Dim PRow As Range
        For Each PRow In PData.Rows
            If PRow.Cells(1, 4).Value = PSelectedAssessor Then  ' Check if fourth column matches the ComboBox
                Dim PRowArray() As Variant
                PRowArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(PRow.Value))
                iR = iR + 1
                For i = 1 To UBound(PRowArray)  ' Add other columns
                    arrRes(i, iR) = CStr(PRowArray(i))
                Next i
            End If
        Next PRow
        If iR > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To 15, 1 To iR)
            .Column = arrRes
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Thank you taller. I just had to change the name of the sheet and it works.
Now I need to understand it and "copy-paste" to create sub when combobox value is changed :)

Thank you. If you could please help also with expanding the condition. Being naive 48yrs never programmer (pascal and C when I was young) I thought that I will simply expand condition
If (PRow.Cells(1, 4).Value = PSelectedAssessor) Then
with  AND (PRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = PSelectedClass)
to have it check also value in another combobox
But I run into "Run-time error 9: subscript out of range"
on the line ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To 15, 1 To iR)
I assume it is because there were no records with selected combination of conditions.
Can you please help?

@taller Fine reply +:); you beat me to it by a few minutes. Anyhow you might be interested in my little work-around proc in the annex of my own post as well as the link reference.

@Radovan Add an If clause to avoid the error from no records.
